# Do While Not IsEmpty(Range("A1")) condition evaluation failure

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with this code, which I made specifically to "load" data in an already create graph, from 3 associated columns like this:

```
Data1 X1 Y1
Data2 X2 Y2
Data3 X3 Y3
```

Its intended behavior is very simple, It selects the active cell, and enters a loop:
select the first graph of the sheet, evaluate if active cell is not empty, if it is, it should go outside the loop and end the macro, if it isn't, it then adds new series to it, puts Y as abscissa value and puts X as ordinate value, increments a tracking value which allows to increase the number of the next series in a graph (it was initialized outside the loop as 1), changes the row of the active cell with the one immediately below.

The problem is that it never goes outside of the loop (and eventually crashes because you can't add more that 256 series to a graph, which I improved the code in another version with a if condition to make it better, it works; but still adds empty series; which are very tedious to delete and may mess with things if left there).

It seems that the condition: Do While Not IsEmpty(Range("A1")) fails to evaluate correctly.
I tried to use Do While Not IsEmpty(Range("A1").value) instead, or Do While IsEmpty(Range("A1")); Do While Not IsEmpty(Selection) (which send back an error about global), I tried a lot of other things but I think my type of value is ok, it is a boolean, so it should work as is.
I also tried on a new workbook with a new sheet and only one line to be sure nothing had messed with cells before and would have changed their state so they would not be empty for the program,
but actually while I thought about the most evident mistakes, I still fail to obtain the correct behavior.

```
Sub ScatterSeries()

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Serie = 1
    Do While Not IsEmpty(Range("A1"))
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
        ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Serie).Name = ActiveCell
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Serie).XValues = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Serie).Values = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
        Serie = Serie + 1
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Loop

End Sub
```

I read few references like that https://www.udemy.com/blog/excel-vba-do-while/ or http://www.fontstuff.com/ebooks/free/fscodeloops.pdf but I fail to see what I am doing differently, which would cause the program to be wrong.
Could anyone please give me insights about that? I feel really stupid now.
Thanks.

(I must say that I am a beginner with vba, so it is possible I made very obvious mistakes, I just run some actions to see what would appear in a macro, then tweaked this with scraps of code read in examples here and there (I still plan to learn properly the language but I had to solve the problem for today...:/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IsEmpty() is used in VBA to check if a variable has been assigned a property, not to check if a cell is blank. Also your offset method isn't properly declared.

Use something like this:

```
Sub ScatterSeries()

Range("A1").Activate

Serie = 1

While Not ActiveCell = ""

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Serie).Name = ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Serie).XValues = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Serie).Values = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value

    Serie = Serie + 1

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Wend

End Sub
```

Also, you should always specify the .Value property of the range object (Yes, I know it's the default method of a Range object) but when you are testing a condition on the value, you want to be sure that it's definitely looking at the value and nothing else.

Comment: +1 for `IsEmpty() is used in VBA to check if a variable has been assigned a property, not to check if a cell is blank.` I believe that is probably the main bug here.

Comment: Yeah, I answered to that below (comments are too short), I saw full pages of code presented as "reference" using this.
And ActiveCell = "" solves the problem perfectly (while some other details of the answer won't work, see below). Thanks

Comment: -1 The statement about IsEmpty() is very misleading/incorrect:  it works perfectly well to check if a cell is empty because the Range("a1") gets converted to a variant which is then tested by IsEmpty()

Comment: Well, actually, it didn't, since that's the only detail that I need to change in my code to make it work.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams you are correct about the variant conversion, however this relies on the use of IntelliSense in VBA which other programming languages lack, so (in my humble opinion) it's a mis-use of VBA's abilities. Plus the test should actually be on the *value* of the range object, not the object itself so in this particular instance it was incorrect - however I fully appreciate that a similar use if IsEmpty() would be completely valid in another scenario.

Comment: @SO Thats also incorrect: it has nothing whatsoever to do with intellisense and using it that way IS testing the value of the range object: I suggest that you try it yourself to verify that the use of IsEmpty(Range("A1")) works correctly

Comment: @Ando - Your original code does not work because it never changes Range("A1") - it only changes the active cell.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams - I didn't discount your logic at all - I agree that it can be used that way, however it will only return true if the cell is *truly* empty - If the cell contains a formula that returns a null string then that evaluation will return False. My argument was that in this situation a direct string comparison should be used instead. I wasn't attempting to take anything away from your suggestion so my apologies if my comment came across in that manner!

Answer (score 1):

Tried this as a comment but it was too long.

It looks like the problem is an infinite loop. The cell A1, I assume, has something in it (likely the text Data1?) and nothing in your code ever looks anywhere else or changes the value in this cell.

```
Do While Not IsEmpty(Range("A1"))
```

You already have an integer "counter" named Serie, so I would suggest just altering the Do While to be

```
Do While Not IsEmpty(Range("A1").Offset(Serie-1,0))
```

The reason for the minus one is Serie is set to 1 initially and you actually want offset zero in your first pass.

If this doesn't solve your problem post again and I can take a better look later in the day.

Answer (score 1):

Would have commented your answers but it's way too long.

Thanks [S O](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4240221/s-o)
You were right about IsEmpty, I read lots of code about using IsEmpty for evaluating empty cells, but that won't work while just changing
'Do While Not IsEmpty(Range("A1"))
  to  Do While Not ActiveCell = ""
in my previous code.

I actually just changed this condition, because  the one you provided didn't work for me*, and it made it work without problem.
THANKS!

- your code send me back error 1004, "error defined by application or object", it doesn't seem to like the line:
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Serie).XValues = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value.
  I also read that Wend was "obsolete" syntax, so I didn't use that.

But I retain the lesson about syntax improvement about value I'll take these gladly, as I said I am only a tweaker regarding VBA, I didn't learn syntax properly.
I just have now to understand why these won't work for me there.

[Dave Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3454994/dave-brown) solution also works nearly flawlessly with the original code, it adds only one empty series in the end
since it won't go out of the loop on the first empty cell but only on the second.
Which is something that I can correct by setting "Series" at 0 at first and changing the way/moment it is incremented**.
You were right about the infinite loop, for me it was quite evident it was one but I didn't mentionned that because I believed the while evaluation was somewhat wrong, while it only evaluated the wrong thing.
On the other hand, I failed at first to understand why, since I did believe that "Range ("A1")" was changed by the fact of changing the active cell. Which is not the case. Beginner failure.

**but changing [Dave Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3454994/dave-brown) solution to

```
Serie = 0
Do While Not IsEmpty(Range("A1").Offset(Serie, 0))
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    Serie = Serie + 1
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Serie).Name = ActiveCell
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Serie).XValues = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Serie).Values = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
Loop
```

Still makes the same mistake...? It should not, since it evaluate the current cell at start, and "Series" is now equal to current total vertical offset...

In the end, I came up with another solution which is :
Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
which also solves the problem (but as [S O](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4240221/s-o) pointed it out, it is not perfect as improper use of "IsEmpty" is made)

Answer (score -1):

Not very elegant, but this one works

```vb
Private Sub Countpatienten()
    q = 2

    With Worksheets("Besuchsplan")
      Do Until Cells(q, A).Value = ""
        q = q + 1
      Loop
    End With
 
    Worksheets("Grunddaten").Cells(2, B) = q
End Sub
```